# Java: "If user does not input X, Y, Z, do this"

Tags: java

Having an error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to java.lang.String when I try to do this (Error on line with **):

```
 ...
        case("division"):{
                        System.out.println("Enter first number to find quotient: ");
                        num1 = scan.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Enter second number to find quotient: ");
                        num2 = scan.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Quotient is " + (num1 / num2));
                        break;
                        }

                **case(!ask.equals("addition") || !ask.equals("subtraction") || !ask.equals("multiplication") || !ask.equals ("division")): {**

                        System.out.println("User input is not valid. Please specify what kind of operation you want to perform on 2 numbers: addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division. Type 'terminate' to terminate this program.");
```

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
!ask.equals("addition") || !ask.equals("subtraction") || !ask.equals("multiplication") || !ask.equals ("division")
```

produce a **boolean**, when a `String` is expected.

When doing `switch-case` for a string, every case must have a value of `String` in the brackets.

Instead, you should do:

```
case ("addition") :{}
case ("subtraction") :{}
case ("multiplication") :{}
case ("division") :{
    System.out.println("User input is not valid. Please specify what kind of operation you want to perform on 2 numbers: addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division. Type 'terminate' to terminate this program.");
    break;
}
default: {
    break;
}
```

In the scenario above, if the string you are `switch`ing is equals to `addition`, `subtraction` or `multiplication`, it keeps looping until it gets to `division`, and that is where the code you need is executed

Comment: If it's `addition`, `subtraction`, `multiplication`, or `division` it's _invalid_?

Comment: @August I don't know, I just made his implementation work correctly. What mildstormer tries to achieve is up to him.

Comment: I'd assume he wants the input to be invalid if it's _not_ any of those choices.

Comment: @August I think, he wants the input to be invalid, if it is not any of the choices in the cases above (in the shown part of the code, it is just the "division" case.

Comment: "every case must have a value of `String` in the brackets." -- actually, brackets (parentheses) are not needed, and it's actually pretty unusual to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you write a `switch` statement, you should include `default:` as your last case.  This just means "do this, if none of the other conditions are true".  It's what you want here.

```
switch(ask) {
    case "addition":
        // do something
        break;
    case "subtraction":
        // do something
        break;
    case "multiplication":
        // do something
        break;
    case "division":
        // do something
        break;
    default:
        // do something
}
```

Incidentally, if you did want a boolean expression for `ask` is not `"addition", "subtraction", "multiplication", "division"` then you'd want to use `&&` instead of `||` in an expression like

```
(!ask.equals("addition") && !ask.equals("subtraction") && !ask.equals("multiplication") && !ask.equals ("division")
```

because

```
(!ask.equals("addition") || !ask.equals("subtraction") || !ask.equals("multiplication") || !ask.equals ("division"))
```

is always `true`, no matter what `ask` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(string){
  case string : ...

}
```

In your example your switch case exptecting string value but your expression `(!ask.equals("addition") || !ask.equals("subtraction") || !ask.equals("multiplication") || !ask.equals ("division")):` producing boolean result.

Don't put expression in switch case, put string which you want to match, expressions such as you provided used in `if` condition not switch.

To match multiple conditions you can do,

```
case ("addition") :
case ("subtraction") :
case ("multiplication") :
case ("division") :
    System.out.println("Here your all condition get match, now do expected here");
    break;

default: {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason provided by @Victor2748 is correct. However, I see that you want to produce that special String output when the String input by user is something other than addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. So the code will not look like what he is suggesting, rather it would look something like this.

...

```
case("division"): {}

default: System.out.println("User input is not valid. Please specify what kind of operation you want to perform on 2 numbers: addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division. Type 'terminate' to terminate this program.");
```

In `switch` statements, `default` is executed only when no other `case` can be executed. `default` is like `else` in `if-else`. Just like `else` is executed only if the first `if` and subsequent `else if` statements cannot be executed, similarly, `default` works only when none of the `case` statements can be executed. So the statement

`!ask.equals("addition") || !ask.equals("subtraction") || !ask.equals("multiplication") || !ask.equals ("division")` is redundant.

Hope this helps !